# An experiment is repeated, and the first success occurs on the 8th attempt. What is the success probability for which this is most likely to happen?

Tags: probability

An experiment is repeated, and the first success occurs on the 8th attempt. What is the success probability for which this is most likely to happen?

So we want to find $p$ between $0$ and $1$ which maximizes $(1-p)^{7}p$. To do this we could take the derivative and find all the critical points:

$$(1-p)^7 - 7(1-p)^6p = 0$$

But I don't know how to get the roots of this equation by hand. What can I do instead to solve this problem?

Comment: That is only the correct likelihood if it was determined before the experiment that there would be $8$ attempts. This is known as the "stopping condition." If the stopping condition is that you continue until you get a success, then you need a different likelihood.

Comment: Try factoring out $(1-p)^6$ !!!

Comment: @SeanLake Could you explain?

Comment: If the number of trials is fixed and non-random, $N$, then the number of successes is binomially distributed: $P(n) = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} p^n (1-p)^{N-n}.$ When the experiment is to continue until a success is acquired, then stop, the probability of different outcomes has to be different because $N$ is random then, too, and $n=1$ always. I don't know what the probability distribution is, so I just asked that question.

Comment: @SeanLake The question implies that we continue until the first success.

Comment: @SeanLake The question also implies that "first success is on the 8th attempt" is a random event that occurs with some probability, so it was not decided before the experiment began. I think the question makes sense as stated, and the attempt to solve it is correct, just not complete.

Comment: @SeanLake It is a geometric distribution, not a binomial distribution

Comment: I disagree that the question was that clearly worded, but was wrong about the likelihood being wrong. The likelihood was correct as described by the geometric distribution.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the experiment was supposed to be run. The likelihood is simply $\mathcal{P}(\text{observation}|\text{parameter})$, and _our observation is the result of $8$ first trials_, not "the number of first success was $8$ and something else happened after that"  nor "there was one success in first $8$ trials (but the order is unspecified)". For our observation, the likelihood is $(1-p)^7 p$. It doesn't even matter if we intended to do $100$ trials but stopped after the $8$th trial because of a fire alarm.

Comment: As @JiK says, the issue of whether one stops after 8 trials, or a success, or whatever, is irrelevant (so long as it’s continued *at least* until a success or 8 trials).  What *is* required is the assumption that the experiments are independent and identically distributed — which is to some extent implicit in describing it as “an experiment is repeated”.

Comment: This is a very bad question.  It's impossible to know the success probability after only one success: for all you know it was a one-in-a-million chance and the experimenters got lucky on the 8th iteration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go ahead and solve for where the derivative is zero:
$$(1-p)^7-7(1-p)^6p=0$$
$$(1-p)^6(1-p-7p)=0$$
$$(1-p)^6(1-8p)=0$$
$$1-p=0\text{ or }1-8p=0$$
$$p=1\text{ or }p=\frac18$$
We reject $p=1$ because then the experiment would succeed on the first try. $p=0$ can also be rejected for obvious reasons, so $p=\frac18$.

Comment: Faster, I think, to rule out $p=0$ and $p=1$ rather than to apply the second derivative test.

Comment: @Hurkyl that has been taken into account. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Where does your $p=0$ come from? You reject it obviously, but there are only two extremal points, right?

Comment: @example because $0$ is an endpoint which you would check normally

Answer (score 4):

$$(1-p)^7-7(1-p)^6p=(1-p)^6(1-p-7p)=(1-p)^6(1-8p)$$
Thus, for extremum,
$$(1-p)^6(1-8p)=0$$
$$p=1 \text{ or }p=\frac18$$

The boundary values are $p=0$ and $p=1$, both which constitute zero probability. Moreover, by the second derivative test, it can be seen that $p=\frac18$ is a point of maximum.

Hence,
$$p=\frac18$$

Comment: (but the second derivative test is superfluous here -- the maximum must be either at $p=0$, $p=1/8$, or $p=1$, so as soon as you rule out $p=0$ and $p=1$, you're done)

Comment: @Hurkyl I agree, that was my intention of using "Moreover,..", to show that it is another way to get the same thing.